# How to post data from Angular project to ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: html, typescript, asp.net-web-api, angular-httpclient

I have an Angular client application and an ASP.NET MVC server side project. In the client project I have a user registration form:

```
<div class="center-content">
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Login/Register</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Angular tutorial</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-tab-group>
          <mat-tab label="Login">
            <!-- Login code -->
          </mat-tab>
          
          <mat-tab label="Register">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
              <input id="rEmail" type="email" matInput placeholder="Email" value="item.remail" [(ngModel)]="remail">
              <mat-icon matSuffix>email</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>      
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
              <input id="rPassword" type="password" matInput placeholder="Password" value="item.rpassword" [(ngModel)]="rpassword">
              <mat-icon matSuffix>vpn_key</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
              <input id="rRepeatPassword" type="password" matInput placeholder="Password" value="item.rcpassword" [(ngModel)]="rcpassword">
              <mat-icon matSuffix>vpn_key</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
            <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="register()">Register</button>
          </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>  
      </mat-card-content>  
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

In my `.ts` file I have the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {}

  email:string;
  password:string;
  rEmail = (document.getElementById("rEmail") as HTMLInputElement).value;
  rPassword = (document.getElementById("rPassword") as HTMLInputElement).value;
  rRepeatPassword = (document.getElementById("rRepeatPassword") as HTMLInputElement).value;
  http:HttpClient
 
   constructor(private snackBar:MatSnackBar, private router: Router){}

   register() {     
    this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:54111/RegisterController/Value', { }).subscribe(data => {
      this.rEmail = data.email;
  })
}

   login() {
     //loginCode
   }
 }
```

In the ASP.NET MVC server-side project, I added a class to get the values sent from the client project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ServerSide.Controllers
{
    public class RegisterController : ApiController
    {
        string emailRegister;

        [HttpGet]
        public string Value(string email)
        {            
            emailRegister = email;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***EmailRegister " + emailRegister + "***");
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the "Register" button, I want to send the values entered in the Register form to the server-side project.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you used [HttpGet] attribute on the .Net side and Post method on the Angular side. If you print the error and share it, we can be of full help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).